# I need to grab data from html of a remote url

Tags: php, html, regex, html-parsing, web-scraping

I need a script that accepts this ul:

```
<ul id="activitylist">
    <li class="activitybit forum_thread">
        <div class="avatar"> <img alt="secret team's Avatar" src="images/misc/unknown.gif" title="secret team's Avatar"> </div>
        <div class="content hasavatar">
        <div class="datetime"> <span class="date">Today,&nbsp;<span class="time">11:25pm</span></span> </div>
        <div class="title"> <a class="username" href="member.php/436070-secret-team">secret team</a> started a thread <a href="showthread.php/415403-Allow-VIDEO-Code-missing-in-settings">'Allow [VIDEO] Code' missing in settings</a> </div>
        <div class="views">0 replies | 0 view(s)</div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

There are 10 to 15 child li in one ul. I need thread name of every child li where thread has  0 replies. I posted one example li above. So for that example I need this text:

```
'Allow [VIDEO] Code' missing in settings
```

where this div has 0 replies as a text:

```
 <div class="views">0 replies | 0 view(s)</div>
```

I have this sample code but it is not working correctly.

```
<?php
$request_url = 'https://www.vbulletin.com/forum/activity.php';

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $request_url); // The url to get links from
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); // We want to get the respone
$result = curl_exec($ch);

$sPattern = "/<li class=\"activitybit forum_thread\">(.*?)<\/li>/s";
preg_match_all($sPattern, $result, $parts);
$links = $parts[1];
foreach ($links as $link) {
    if (stripos($link, "0 replies") !== false) {
        echo $link . "<br>";
    }
}
curl_close($ch);
?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a regex that will parse **any** kind of HTML:

```
$regex = new DOMDocument;
$regex->loadHTML($html);
```

Now serious. DOMDocument has parsed all of your HTML. You can now use [these](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) and [these](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domnode.php) functions to walk over tags and extract their attribute and contents. But it is much easier to use a companion class called [DOMXPath](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php):

```
$xpath = new DOMXpath($regex);
foreach ($xpath->query("//ul[@id='activitylist']/li") as $li) {
    $view = $xpath->query(".//div[@class='views']", $li)->item(0);
    $link = $xpath->query(".//div[@class='title']/a", $li)->item(1);
    if (preg_match("/0 replies/", $view->nodeValue)) {
        echo $link->nodeValue . " (" . $link->getAttribute("href") . ")\n";
    }
}
```

This will output few warnings about your HTML not being perfect plus this:

```
'Allow [VIDEO] Code' missing in settings (showthread.php/415403-Allow-VIDEO-Code-missing-in-settings)
```

You can read more about using <del>Regex</del> PHP to parse HTML [here](http://htmlparsing.com/php.html). A comprehensive list of XPath examples is [available here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256086.aspx).

Comment: Somehow helpful but remove the sarcasm and add a real explanation why this could help solving the problem

Comment: Thank you salman.$regex->loadHTML($html);here how i can get html contents in $html variable from a remote url.?can i use curl or i need to use file_get_contents .?please help me i need to finish this today.Thanks.

Comment: If you look at the documentation carefully you will notice this method [`DOMDocument::loadHTMLFile`](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtmlfile.php). It should accept `http://url`. You can also use `file_get_contents("http://url")`. If both methods fail use cURL.

Comment: Salman you are genious man.
you have solved my issue.i give you 100 marks.can you give me your email.i wanna in contact with you.promise i will only contact you when i really need your help.

thanks again salman.

Comment: salman i will add a comment here if i will stuck any point till that please keep rechecking this post.God blessed you.